# PHP: check if empty line ("\n")

Tags: php, is-empty

I'm using an API in order to retrieve some temperature and location values in JSON format.
I'm writing the output in a plain text cachefile.

However a temperature station may fail reporting the temperature value, and in that case my output will be an empty line (\n). I want to handle such case by displaying "N/A" for a non-reporting station.

Here's a typical cachefile with the first station reporting temperature and location, and the second station shut down (reporting two empty lines):

```
27.6
Napoli-Posillipo
(an empty line)
(an empty line)
```

I tried with:

```
$display = file($cachename);
$temperature[0] = $display[0];
$location[0] = $display[1];
$temperature[1] = $display[2];
$location[1] = $display[3];

$temp_avg = (($temperature[0]+$temperature[1])/2); //average temperature

if($temperature[0] = "\n"){ //if weather station is not reporting data
   $temperature[0] = "N/A";
   $temp_avg = "N/A";
}

if($temperature[1] = "\n"){
   $temperature[1] = "N/A";
   $temp_avg = "N/A";
}


echo "<div id='temperature'><b>".$temperature[0]."</b>°C (".$location[0].") | ";
echo "<b>".$temperature[1]."</b>°C (".$location[1].") | ";
echo "<b>".$temp_avg."</b>°C (avg) | ".$minutes."m".$secondsleft."s ago</div>";
```

However I keep getting "N/A" for both stations, even if the first station correctly reports its temperature value.

> N/A°C (Napoli-Posillipo ) | N/A°C () | N/A°C (avg) | 12m21s ago

I tried with fgets() instead of file(), but I got an error:

> fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in [...] on
>   line 54

I also tried using *if(empty($temperature[foo]))* but it didn't work, because of course *\n != empty*.

Any hints?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) should look like this (note the use of two equal signs):

```
if($temperature[0] == "\n"){
```

Your current code is assigning `"\n"` to `$temperature[1]`, which evaluates true, which is why the `if` condition is executing.

If you would like to use [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty), which I suggest you do, change your call to [`file()`](http://php.net/file) to:

```
$display = file($cachename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Adding the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag will tell the function not to add newlines (`"\n"`) to the end of the array elements.

Comment: Of course that did the trick. I'm feeling so foolish for such trivial error... thanks.

Comment: @flapane:  No need to feel foolish.  I'm glad you learned something new today!

Comment: file($cachename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES); is my preferred approach. Thanks again for this tip.

Answer (score 6):

You also can use:

```
if (trim($temperature[1]) == '') {
  // Empty line.
}
```